# Dynamically change query type in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I want to achieve that NHibernate queries different types based on a condition. Let's say the condition is `false` then the query should look like this:

```
var myVar = session.Query<TypeWhenFalse>()
                 .Where(a => condition)
```

And when the condition is true it should look like this:

```
var myVar = session.Query<TypeWhenTrue>()
                 .Where(a => condition)
```

Notice the different query types `TypeWhenFalse` and `TypeWhenTrue`. Because of duplicate code, I don't wanna use a `if` clause to set the different types.

Is there a way to do this dynamically in order to avoid an `if` clause? Couldn't find anything helpful in the internet.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is very less to suggest anything confirmed.

You can use generics to achieve this easily. I mean, make this function generic and pass the generic type from outside. This should resolve your concerns.

```
public yourtype GetData<T>()
{
    var myVar = session.Query<T>()
                 .Where(a => condition);
    return myVar;//or whatever
}
```

and your calling code:

```
if(false)
    myVar = GetData<TypeWhenFalse>();
else
    myVar = GetData<TypeWhenTrue>();
```

As you said, you do not want to use `if...else` to avoid redundant code. If you are agreed for little redundancy, consider following solution:

```
var query;
if(false)
    query = session.Query<TypeWhenFalse>();
else
    query = session.Query<TypeWhenTrue>();
var myVar = query.Where(a => condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use generic type method and you can use an extension to implement what you want.

But.. in order to have this to make sense, you need to have both returned types to have common structures implemented by an interface.

See this example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var abc = new List<long>(){ 1,2,3,4};
    var result = abc.AsQueryable().ConvertExtension();
}

public static IQueryable ConvertExtension<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, bool condition=false)
{
    return condition
                ? (IQueryable) source.Select(x => x.ToString()).AsQueryable<string>()
                   : source.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).AsQueryable<int>();
}
```

More about Generic Types: [C# generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters)
More about Interfaces: [Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)

If you implement an interface for both types, you can type your resulting Iqueryable as the interface. The method would be **IQueryable ConvertExtension**

And you would be able to manipulate both Types as it.